# Button does not show in emulator in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, button

I am fresh new to Android development. I just started but when I try to run a basic app with only one button, the button just simply does not show in emulator.
I looked everywhere, even saw similar question on stackOverflow from 2 years ago but answers do not suit my problem
Please tell me what part of code should I add here or anything else to get my app going. Thanks!

> 

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell without showing your code. But I think you did not add constraints to your button.

[Constraint Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woFdI.png)